# Algorithm which allows the backend to find compromised data from the 3rd party service

Tags: algorithm

On my backend I use a 3rd party service which provides currency exchange rates. I use this rate for the funds conversion within the customer’s accounts. As far as this rate affects customers’ money, I have to be sure that it’s legit. Let’s pretend a 3rd party service is experiencing a glitch and returns 100x times bigger rate than it should be, but the backend is going to carry out this transaction, which will lead to huge issues.

The only solution which I found is

1. to retrieve the same rate from 5 different sources
2. to calculate a standard deviation for them
3. to compare the needed rate with an arithmetic average

But this algorithm didn’t work for me — a tiny difference between the rates leads to negative results.

Is there an algorithm which can help me be sure that the rate is correct?

Comment: Can you add an example of actual and desired results?

Comment: It's not possible to know if a number is "correct" or not, but it sounds like you want a number to be near the average (perhaps +- a fraction of a percent) and not exactly the average.